# Table background color and responsive to mobile on Next.js using Tailwindcss

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

```
 <table className="table-auto bg-orange-500">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Song</th>
            <th>Artist</th>
            <th>Year</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr className="bg-orange-500">
            <td>
              The Sliding Mr.
              Boaosjdofijasodifjoasidjfoiasdjfoisajdfoijasdoifjsaoidfjoasidjfaoisjdfoisjdofijnes
              (Next Stop, Pottersville)
            </td>
            <td>Malcolm Lockyer</td>
            <td>1961</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Witchy Woman</td>
            <td>The Eagles</td>
            <td>1972</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Shining Star</td>
            <td>Earth, Wind, and Fire</td>
            <td>1975</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

I have this table example from Tailwind. I want to change the background color for the even number of the item.

```
@layer utilities {
  .no-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }

  .no-scrollbar {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    scrollbar-width: none;
  }

  .tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ccc;
  }
  .tr:nth-child(od) {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
}
```

I tried something like this and also wanted to change the background color of the `thead`.

I did `<thead className="bg-orange-500">` and nothing happens to its background. I couldn't find any information about the background color of the table on the doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes

1. You are using `class` selector `.` for a `element` type .

   Change:

   ```
   .tr:nth-child(even) {
     background-color: #ccc;
   }
   ```

   to:

   ```
   tr:nth-child(even) {
     background-color: #ccc;
   }
   ```
2. Spelling of `odd` has become `od` in your code.

For `thead` `bg-color` try the following code:

```
<table class="table-auto">
  <thead class="bg-cyan-300">
    <tr>
      <th class="px-4 py-2">Item</th>
      <th class="px-4 py-2">Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="px-4 py-2">Item 1</td>
      <td class="px-4 py-2">Value 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="px-4 py-2">Item 2</td>
      <td class="px-4 py-2">Value 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="px-4 py-2">Item 3</td>
      <td class="px-4 py-2">Value 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="px-4 py-2">Item 4</td>
      <td class="px-4 py-2">Value 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<style>
  tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ccc;
  }
    tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #ffec20;
  }
</style>
```

Output:

[image]